# Google Places Android EditText and ListView

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

After a several hours trying to solve this by myself (without any result), I decided to ask for experts!

Because the problem is because the result from API is working well, but when I click in the result line to autocomplete the EditText txtDestination and txtsourceAddress, these fields are not being replaced to the touched information.

Anyone can help to solve this, please? I will be extremely thankful for any help.

Below the code that is not working:

```
    mAutoCompleteList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (txtaddressSource.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                try {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisActivity);
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) thisActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    builder.setMessage("PLEASE CHOOSE A ADDRESS")
                            .setTitle(thisActivity.getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    txtaddressSource.requestFocus();
                                    txtDestination.setText("");
                                    imgDestClose.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    mAutoCompleteList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                setGoogleAddress(position);
            }
        }
    });

private void setGoogleAddress(int position) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        utils.print("", "Place ID == >"+ predictions.getPlaces().get(position).getPlaceID());
        Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, predictions.getPlaces().get(position).getPlaceID())
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                        if (places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Place myPlace = places.get(0);
                            LatLng queriedLocation = myPlace.getLatLng();
                            Log.v("Latitude is", "" + queriedLocation.latitude);
                            Log.v("Longitude is", "" + queriedLocation.longitude);

                            if (strSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("destination")) {
                                placePredictions.strDestAddress = myPlace.getAddress().toString();
                                placePredictions.strDestLatLng = myPlace.getLatLng().toString();
                                placePredictions.strDestLatitude = myPlace.getLatLng().latitude + "";
                                placePredictions.strDestLongitude = myPlace.getLatLng().longitude + "";
                                txtDestination.setText(placePredictions.strDestAddress);
                                Log.v("setGoogleAddress onResult IF destination ", placePredictions.strDestAddress);
                                txtDestination.setSelection(0);
                            } else {
                                placePredictions.strSourceAddress = myPlace.getAddress().toString();
                                placePredictions.strSourceLatLng = myPlace.getLatLng().toString();
                                placePredictions.strSourceLatitude = myPlace.getLatLng().latitude + "";
                                placePredictions.strSourceLongitude = myPlace.getLatLng().longitude + "";
                                txtaddressSource.setText(placePredictions.strSourceAddress);
                                Log.v("setGoogleAddress onResult else ", placePredictions.strSourceAddress);
                                txtaddressSource.setSelection(0);
                                txtDestination.requestFocus();
                                mAutoCompleteAdapter = null;
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.v("setGoogleAddress ELSE ", mAutoCompleteList.toString());
                        }
                        mAutoCompleteList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        if (txtDestination.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                            places.release();
                            if (strSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("destination")) {
                                if (!placePredictions.strDestAddress.equalsIgnoreCase(placePredictions.strSourceAddress)) {
                                    setAddress();
                                } else {
                                    utils.showAlert(thisActivity, getResources().getString(R.string.source_and_destination_not_same));
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            txtDestination.requestFocus();
                            txtDestination.setText("");
                            imgDestClose.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mAutoCompleteList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 queries, a) is edit text part of List view and b)you are setting the String only, not any other data type

Comment: EditText and ListView will work together because I will need the list view to fill the edit text. I have tried everything, but without success all the times. I am still with problem. Have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: @gauravbansal I am still not able to fix it. Please help me.

Comment: The problem is because if (places.getStatus().isSuccess()) { is returning Place query did not complete. Error: Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}